# python & litesql: unicode, utf8, how to do it properly?

Tags: python, sqlite, encoding, utf-8

I have a csv file encoded as utf8 and it has some accented characters, like `Ningún` if I read these lines using the standard `.read()` python function, and then print the results, it works as intended, it prints the accented characters correctly.

Now, I want to insert those lines into a sqlite database. The produced SQL command would be `INSERT INTO x VALUES ('Ningún')`, but then the value stored in the database is `NingÃºn`. When I fetch the value from the database it will give me `NingÃºn`.

I know it is an econding related problem, so what should I do? If I do an `encode('utf-8')` it produces the same result.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error you see. For more information about how to produce good sample programs, see [mcve].

Comment: 3.5.1, it's not actually an error, but just an undesired behaivour. I'll try to make a simple script to show what's going on

Comment: Which OS? Are you using the Windows command-line shell?

Comment: That's part of the problem it seems. I'm developing on Windows and deploying in Linux.

Looks like I have "fixed" the problem. When I'm using Windows I should save the file as "ASCII" (unicode?), and everything will work. But when I move to the Linux server, I must first encode the file as utf-8.

I'm pretty sure I'll forget that in few weeks hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything should just work.  `csv.reader()` decodes its input lines into a Unicode-aware `str`. `sqlite3.execute` accepts `str` as its input type. Consider this program:

```
import csv
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('sample.db') as conn:
    conn.execute('drop table if exists names')
    conn.execute('create table names (age INT, name TEXT)')

with conn:
    with open('x.csv') as input_file:
        input_file = csv.reader(input_file)
        for line in input_file:
            print(type(line[1]), line[1])
            conn.execute('insert into names values(?,?)', line)

for line in conn.execute('select * from names'):
    print(type(line[1]), line[1])
```

Sample input file:

```
49,Ningún
```

Result:

```
$ python3 x3.py 
<class 'str'> Ningún
<class 'str'> Ningún
$ sqlite3 sample.db 'select * from names'
49|Ningún
```

Note that the name retrieved from the database is identical to the name inserted into the database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the problem seems to be related to different OSs, I'm using Windows for developing and Linux for deploying. In Windows my CSV files must be "unicode" (or ASCII as Notepad++ calls them), they won't work on the Linux server. I must encode them as utf-8 before, then it works as it should.

Comment: It's worth noting for other readers, `open('x.csv')` will use the locale to determine the encoding to use to open the file. Under Windows this will be a 8bit codeset and under Linux will likely to be UTF-8 or an iso-8859-* page

Comment: In fact, based on the OP's comment, that's the exact problem they may be having - the file may have come from Excel and therefore encoded to a Windows codepage. The Linux server probably has a `en_*.UTF-8` locale, so is therefore trying to open the file using UTF-8

Comment: @luisfer You're mistaken about "unicode" == "ASCII" in Notepad++. If you save your CSV in "Unicode" via Excel or Notepad (Not ++), you'll get UTF-16. The solution is quite simple however: assuming you're using Western Europe locale in Windows and you're exporting from Excel, change your code to read `open('x.csv',encoding='cp1252')`. You will no longer need to re-encode your CSV file

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack - I believe you are correct. I suggest you post that as an answer.

Comment: I'm not using Excel. I'm using Notepad++ to create a plain file, I mean, it's not that complex, my file only has 3 columns. I'm really sick about this utf-8 to unicode (or ascii or whatever). The error python keeps telling me is something like: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xc3' in position xxx`